# SQL UDF - loop through a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, user-defined-functions

I'm developing a UDF in SQL where by applying the function to a date column, it could generate which dates are holidays or not. It will be comparing to a View (dbo.Holidays) that I have already set up that contains all the public holidays that need to be compared with.

The code I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsHoliday] (
            @Date DATE) 

RETURNS BIT

AS BEGIN
DECLARE @Check BIT

SELECT @Check = CASE WHEN @Date = [Holiday] 
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END
                FROM dbo.Holidays

        RETURN (@Check)
END
```

Sample data (Holidays table):

[image: Holidays]

Intended results:

```
2022-12-12 |    0 |
2020-01-01 |    1 |
2020-01-02 |    1 |
2020-02-06 |    1 |
```

Currently, the results show up as:

```
2022-12-12 |    0 |
2020-01-01 |    1 |
2020-01-02 |    0 |
2020-02-06 |    0 |
```

The issue I'm having so far - when I apply this function to a date column, it only generates '1' to the first public holiday and all the rest are generated as '0'. I feel like the View needs to be looped through each and every row of the dataset that I'm applying the function to. How can I fix it?

Thank you

Tried including a case based in join instead, but didn't work that either.

Comment: In SQL Server `date` and `datetime` are different data types. When comparing date and datetime values the time portion matters - they're only equivalent on the same date at midnight.

Comment: you should use `NOT EXISTS` to check for existence of the `@Date` in table `Holidays` and return the value accordingly

Comment: alwayslearning Sorry, updated it all to be date - the issue is still there.

squirrel how can I apply this? Like this? - SELECT Check = WHERE @Date NOT EXISTS [Holiday] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM dbo.Holidays
RETURN (Check)

Comment: @DaleK just updated it

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current query is just taking the top most (in undefined order) record. You need to check a specific record which you can do with `EXISTS`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsHoliday]
(
    @Date DATE
) 
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Holidays
            WHERE [Holiday] = @Date
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END;
```